# Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.ts(2347)

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, types, mongoose-schema

I have a user schema with typescript, bellow is my interface

```
interface IUser{
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

And below is the user schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>(
 {
   name: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
   },
   email: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
     unique: true,
   validate: [validator.isEmail, "Please provide a valid email"],
   },
   password: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
     minlength: 8,
   },
   isAdmin: {
     type: Boolean,
     required: true,
     default: false,
   },
 },
   {
     timestamps: true,
   }
);

const UserModel = model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

i get the typescript error: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments on the user schema, in express and mongoose with editor visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're getting the error on this line:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>(
```

As it is saying `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments`.

- The `type argument` it's referring to is the generic `<...>`.
- The `function` it's referring to is `Schema`, meaning it doesn't know what `Schema` is (typed as `any`).

This leads me to believe that there is either something wrong with the way you're importing `Schema`, or with the way the typings for `mongoose` have been installed.

I would suggest reading [mongoose - TypeScript Support](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html).

If you cannot figure out what's going wrong, then it would help if you told us:

- How you're importing `Schema`
- What version of mongoose (and possibly `@types/mongoose` you're using)

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same issues, after reading Stanislas' solution it fixed my problem**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

interface ILink {
  discord_id: String;
  linking_code: String;
}

const LinkSchema = new Schema<ILink>({
    discord_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: [true, 'Discord ID name must be unique'],
    },
    linking_code: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    }
});

var Link = mongoose.model('Link', LinkSchema);
module.exports = Link;
```

I updated the imports to this

```
import {Schema, model} from 'mongoose';
```